# Missing space between +--sign in siunitx version [2023-07-31]

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I really dont know what happened, but for a couple of weeks I am approaching the following problem. Using siunitx (e. g. \qty{20+-10}{\mg}), the spacing between the +- sign and the numbers is missing. According to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632298/how-to-change-the-spacing-around-the-plus-or-minus-symbol-in-siunitx), which is from 2022, the author found a solution for this problem.

Here is an example of my code:

```
  \documentclass[listof=totoc, %Abildungsverzeichnis, Bildverz.)
                numbers=noenddot]  %keine Punkte nach Section-Nummerierung
                {scrreprt} %Dokumentklasse
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true,multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}[=2023-07-31]  %SI Einheiten https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=de
    \sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot , %cdot anstelle von Kreuzpr.
        table-number-alignment = center,%zentrierte zahlen
        group-separator=.,% <- ergänzt, default ist \, (also ein kleiner Abstand)
  group-minimum-digits=4% <- ergänzt, default ist 5 (also Gruppierung erst ab 5 Ziffern)
  }
\sisetup{mode = text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_undefine:N \c__siunitx_minus_tl
    \tl_const:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl {\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}\thinspace}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\qty{20+-10}{\mg}
\end{document}
```

Log File:

```
LOG FILE :
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 21.8) (format=lualatex 2021.9.15) 2 AUG 2023 12:54
restricted system commands enabled.
**Tabelle.tex
(./Tabelle.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.18 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/MiKTe
X/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-05-20.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/
fontloader-2021-05-20.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.116
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/MiKTe
X/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 4
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.c
ls
Document Class: scrreprt 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script document class (report)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.s
ty
Package: scrkbase 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.st
y
Package: scrbase 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.s
ty
Package: scrlfile 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-h
ook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.st
y
Package: scrlogo 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
368.
))
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.s
ty
Package: tocbasic 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box50
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic) because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrreprt) file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 248
6.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11p
t.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/
MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.s
ty
Package: typearea 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count179
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea) DIV = 10
(typearea) BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea) \paperwidth = 597.50793pt
(typearea) \textwidth = 418.25555pt
(typearea) DIV departure = -6%
(typearea) \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea) \oddsidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea) \paperheight = 845.04694pt
(typearea) \textheight = 595.80026pt
(typearea) \topmargin = -25.16531pt
(typearea) \headheight = 17.0pt
(typearea) \headsep = 20.40001pt
(typearea) \topskip = 11.0pt
(typearea) \footskip = 47.6pt
(typearea) \baselineskip = 13.6pt
(typearea) on input line 1742.
)
\c@part=\count180
\c@chapter=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\chapter on input line 5716.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\section on input line 5727.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\section on input line 5727.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt) for `\part on input line 5736.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subsection on input line 5746.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subsection on input line 5746.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subsubsection on input line 5756.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subsubsection on input line 5756.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\paragraph on input line 5767.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\paragraph on input line 5767.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subparagraph on input line 5777.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt) for `\subparagraph on input line 5777.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box51
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic) because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6957.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count187
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic) because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6974.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count188
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7143.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
Rollback for package 'siunitx' requested -> date 2023-07-31.
Best approximation is the release introduced on 2021-05-17.
Package: siunitx 2021-09-06 v3.0.29 A comprehensive (SI) units package
\l__siunitx_angle_tmp_dim=\dimen139
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box52
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box53
\l__siunitx_compound_count_int=\count189
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/translations/translati
ons.sty
Package: translations 2021/01/17 v1.10a internationalization of LaTeX2e package
s (CN)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count190
)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmd
s.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.
sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
))
\l__siunitx_number_exponent_fixed_int=\count191
\l__siunitx_number_min_decimal_int=\count192
\l__siunitx_number_min_integer_int=\count193
\l__siunitx_number_round_precision_int=\count194
\l__siunitx_number_group_minimum_int=\count195
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen140
))
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 149.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.de
f
File: luatex.def 2021/06/01 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_box=\box54
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_dim=\dimen141
\l__siunitx_table_column_width_dim=\dimen142
\l__siunitx_table_integer_box=\box55
\l__siunitx_table_decimal_box=\box56
\l__siunitx_table_before_box=\box57
\l__siunitx_table_after_box=\box58
\l__siunitx_table_before_dim=\dimen143
\l__siunitx_table_carry_dim=\dimen144
\l__siunitx_unit_tmp_int=\count196
\l__siunitx_unit_position_int=\count197
\l__siunitx_unit_total_int=\count198
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3
keys2e.sty
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-08-27 L3 programming layer (loader)
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lu
atex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count199
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box59
))
Package: l3keys2e 2021-08-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package siunitx Info: Option "separate-uncertainty" has been deprecated in
(siunitx) this release.
(siunitx)
(siunitx) Use "uncertainty-mode = separate" as a replacement.
Package siunitx Info: Option "multi-part-units = single" has been deprecated
(siunitx) in this release.
(siunitx)
(siunitx) Use "separate-uncertainty-units = single" as a
(siunitx) replacement.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2021/04/20 v2.5e Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen145
\ar@mcellbox=\box60
\extrarowheight=\dimen146
\NC@list=\toks19
\extratabsurround=\skip64
\backup@length=\skip65
\ar@cellbox=\box61
))
Package translations Info: No language package found. I am going to use `englis
h' as default language. on input line 215.
(./Tabelle.aux)
\openout1 = Tabelle.aux
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
15.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 215.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 215.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 215.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 215.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/translations/dicts/tra
nslations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 215.
(C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.m
kii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count266
\scratchdimen=\dimen147
\scratchbox=\box62
\nofMPsegments=\count267
\nofMParguments=\count268
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count269
\MPscratchDim=\dimen148
\MPnumerator=\count270
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count271
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) [1
{C:/Users/Yannik/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./Tabelle.aux)
*File List*
scrreprt.cls 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
scrlogo.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (logo)
keyval.sty 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
tocbasic.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty 2021/06/25 v3.34 KOMA-Script package (type area)
siunitx.sty 2021-09-06 v3.0.29 A comprehensive (SI) units package
translations.sty 2021/01/17 v1.10a internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
(CN)
etoolbox.sty 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
pdftexcmds.sty 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
iftex.sty 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
ltxcmds.sty 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
amstext.sty 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
color.sty 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
luatex.def 2021/06/01 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for luatex
l3keys2e.sty 2021-08-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
expl3.sty 2021-08-27 L3 programming layer (loader)
l3backend-luatex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
array.sty 2021/04/20 v2.5e Tabular extension package (FMi)
ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
supp-pdf.mkii
***********
)
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
8295 strings out of 478146
100000,662416 words of node,token memory allocated
431 words of node memory still in use:
3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 53 glue_spec,
4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
avail lists: 2:43,3:6,4:12,5:28,6:2,7:48,9:34,11:3
28493 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
23 fonts using 2647927 bytes
108i,7n,102p,10739b,446s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<//?/c:/users/yannik/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmro
man10-regular.otf>
Output written on Tabelle.pdf (1 page, 3734 bytes).
PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

I hope none of my options will create this problem, but just in case I've not ruled them out.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot! -Yannik

Comment: Works for me with the current release. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the `File list` from the log in the question?

Comment: Off-topic, but the hack with `\c__siunitx_minus_tl` is from v2: it does nothing at all in v3

Comment: Thank you, Joseph, I've just uploaded the Log File (the right way?). :)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147613/discussion-on-question-by-yannik-k-missing-space-between-sign-in-siunitx-vers); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.